# Why is output buffering behavior of an ordinary servlet and Jersey servlet different?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jersey, embedded-jetty

Output buffering behavior and number of chunks used during the response changes
depending on whether the response was from a ordinary servlet or from a resource of the Jersey container servlet.

I am using a dummy servlet and a dummy Jersey resource for the tests.
Both are printing a multiple of 256 characters (255 'a' and 1 '\n', these are not significant, just random choices).

Jetty has a default output buffer of 32kB, when the output content exceeds that size and if Content-Length is not explicitly set, Jetty will use chunked transfer encoding.

However, when the same test is done from a Jersey resource regardless of output size Jetty always uses chunked transfer encoding, and chunks are split at 16kB not 32kB.

I navigated sources of both but couldn't find the reason. I would really be glad if anyone could share their insights into this.

**Servlet Test Code**

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String baseString;

    public Test() {
        super();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++)
            sb.append("a");
        sb.append("\n");
        baseString = sb.toString();
     }

     private void writeOutput(int count, PrintWriter writer) {
        for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
            writer.print(baseString);
        }
     }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        writeOutput(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count")),response.getWriter());
     }

}
```

**Jersey Resource Test Code**

```
@Path("/")
public class JerseyTest {

private String baseString;

public JerseyTest() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 255 ; i++)
        sb.append("a");
    sb.append("\n");
    baseString = sb.toString();
}

@GET
@Produces("text/html;charset=UTF-8")
public String get(@Context HttpServletResponse response,@QueryParam("count")int count) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i<count; i++) {
        sb.append(baseString);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}   
}
```

**Setup**

- Embedded Jersey 8.1.7.v20120910
- Jersey 1.14 (using Jersey Servlet Container)

**Response for count=1 (i.e. output size 256 bytes)**

- Servlet: Content-Length set
- Jersey: Content-Length not set, chunked encoding is used , 1 chunk

**Response for count=128 (i.e. output size 32kB)**

- Servlet: Content-Length not set, chunked encoding is used , 1 chunk
- Jersey: Content-Length not set, chunked encoding is used , 2 chunks (split at 16kB)

**Response for count=256 (i.e. output size 64kB)**

- Servlet: Content-Length not set, chunked encoding is used , 2 chunks
- Jersey: Content-Length not set, chunked encoding is used , 4 chunks

Anyone has any ideas for the reason of this difference?

**Update 1:** Jersey sets an internal buffer size of 8kB, but this still doesn't explain the 16kB behavior I'm seeing. If Jersey is flushing per 8kB, then I should have seen 8kB chunks not 16kB (this behavior is present in the ordinary servlet case)